# Best way to visualize mysql database

Tags: mysql

I need a software so I can visualize a mysql database and see data entries. I need to be able edit entries/moderate. Any suggestions? I can log into the mysql in terminal but can't see any of the data; only the tables. Thank you!

Comment: Try MySQL Workbench: http://mysqlworkbench.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not MySQL itself? The Community Edition, for example. It includes MySQL Workbench, which has a visual environment. You can get it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)